# How to select columns from active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Devise to set the current user and current company,

I have an active record of User which contains certain fields that should not be exposed in some cases like password etc.

#<User email:*** password:***>

How can we select only selected attributes and keep them as active record object only.

output should be
#<User email:****>

current_user is getting created from devise helper.

Answer (score -1):

In Active Record, you can use the select method to choose the attributes you want to retrieve from the database. Here's an example:

`current_user.select(:email)`

This will return a new Active Record object with only the email attribute populated, while keeping the other attributes as nil.

Note that select returns a new instance of the Active Record object and does not modify the original object. To persist the changes, you need to assign the result to a new variable or update the original object:

`selected_user = current_user.select(:email)`

Alternatively, you can use the attributes method to retrieve a hash of attribute names and values, and then select only the desired attributes:

`attributes = current_user.attributes.slice("email")`
`selected_user = User.new(attributes)`

This will give you a new instance of the User model with only the selected attributes.

Comment: `current_user` is an instance of `User`. `select` is not an instance method so this will not work. Technically `select` would be [`Kernel#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#method-i-select) but that is not at all the same thing. You can use the `attributes` concept proposed though.