# How to select attributes when devise setting current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

At this point, I'm not sure how or where the helper current_user is loaded. I'd like to select only certain properties from the user table, but devise to
`select * from users` table

I want to do something like `select (id, email, additional_stuff) from users`

I would like to be able to modify the current_user set by devise so I can optimise my application from a security point.

Using Rails version 7.0.4
RUby Version 3.1.3

Comment: Could you elaborate on the security standpoint? Current user object is only 'exposed' for the authenticated user himself. What's to worry about here? - what's your case?

Comment: Certain class in the application use the current_user object, one such class is template creator. There one can do current_user.token which has a security risk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select columns from active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433494/how-to-select-columns-from-active-record)

Comment: The fact that they can access `current_user` at all is the bigger security risk. This smells like putting makeup on a pig.

Comment: But who can call current_user.token? I assume it is the application itself if needed and that should be fine. To keep my point short, and without having 100% understood your case, I think #current_user can not be a 'threat'. Nevertheless Max's answer should work but I would 'reverse' it cause its more safe ->  User.select(*User.attribute_names.reject { |attr| attr == 'token' })

Answer (score 0):

Devise is build on top of the Warden gem which handles the grunt work of actually authenticating users.

Fetching the user from the database is done by the [`Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden/Manager#serialize_from_session-class_method) method which can be reconfigured.

```
# app/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.serialize_from_session(:users) do |id|
    User.select(:id, :email, :additional_stuff)
        .find(id)
  end
end
```

However, I'm very sceptical that this will have any real benefits to security and you'll most likely just end up breaking parts of Devise/the rest of your application. For example authenticating the user for password updates may fail unless you load the password digest.

Make sure you have tests covering your whole Devise implementation before you monkey around with it.

It's hard to know what you actually mean by "Certain class in the application use the current_user object, one such class is template creator" . But that smells like a huge gaping security hole in itself. If this is running code that comes from the user it should not have access to the entire view context (for example the `current_user` method). If the user has access to the actual object then whats preventing them from querying and getting any missing data?

If you really need this feature you should be sandboxing it in a separate renderer (not using Rails build in render methods) which only has access to the context and data you explicitly pass (like a struct or decorator representing a user) which is deemed safe.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing to try and avoid loading our user's introduction on every page load. I tried max's answer and it didn't really work for some reason.

What I am doing is overriding the `serialize_from_cookie` and `serialize_from_session` class methods in the `user.rb` class.

They look like this now:

```
#user.rb
def self.serialize_from_cookie(*args)
    id, token, generated_at = *args

    record = select('id, ...').find(id)
    record = record.first if record.kind_of? Array

    #record = to_adapter.get(id)      <- what it used to be

    record if record && record.remember_me?(token, generated_at)
end

def self.serialize_from_session(key, salt)
    record = select('id, ...').find(key.first)
    
    #record  = to_adapter.get(key) <- what it used to be
    
    record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
end
```

seems to work! This doesn't cover the initial sign in, which will probably override a different method, but it works for most page loads. If you have multiple scopes, you may want to wrap this into a concern.